# Do I really have to scan memory twice to do a memcmp + memcpy?

Tags: c++, optimization

Consider the following function:

```
int memcmp_and_memcpy(void * x, const void * y, size_t n) {
  int c = memcmp(x, y, n);
  memcpy(x, y, n);
  return c;
}
```

Is it possible to do this more efficiently? Scanning the relevant memory twice seems inefficient.

EDIT: I'm looking for an industrial strength solution that performs well for a variety of inputs, especially when `x` and `y` are identical for the first `m` bytes, where `0<<m<=n`. Vectorization is a must.

Comment: Unless you're doing this many, many times in a tight loop, it's almost certainly not going to matter.

Comment: what will this be used for?

Comment: Profile and look at generated assembly first. Test with your expected test case or a reasonable representation of it. Whether or not two passes is inefficient really depends.

Comment: Why is memcpy called twice in the first place?

Comment: A `memcmp` intrinsic will return on the first *difference* detection. Worst-case (identical buffers) this *could* scan twice, but since both are likely intrinsics in release code, the final asm may already be optimized for you. `-S` is your friend.

Comment: If the data doesn't fit in the lower level CPU caches, the only thing that's going to matter is how many passes you make over the data. The assembly becomes irrelevant.

Comment: In many cases, replacement is much faster than search, determine if replacement, replace.

Comment: Actually, that's a good example to look whether your compiler supports loop fusion. Enable assembly output and look into the source. Probably, you don't need to optimize it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it more efficiently, but it will take work. On the one hand, you can easily eliminate the duplicate pass over the memory by writing your own loop which makes a single pass over all of the bytes.

This will almost certainly be faster on large arrays due to the improved use of memory bandwidth.

For small copies, it is not clear that you will win, because implementations of memcmp and memcpy are themselves quite optimized, and work with larger units of data than just bytes; a naive byte-based implementation may lose.  It will take work to repeat the same kinds of optimizations in your compare-and-copy.

Naive, untested:

```
int memcmpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t size)
{ 
  unsigned char *d = dst;
  const unsigned char *s = src;
  int compare = 0;

  for (; size--; s++, d++) {
    int sv = *s;
    int dv = *d;

    /* Thansks to Ben Voigt: if dv == sv, we can 
       avoid checking for the first difference, and skip
       the data move from source to dest: */
    if (dv == sv)
      continue;

    if (!compare) {
       if (dv < sv)
         compare = -1;
       else if (dv > sv)
         compare = 1;
    }

    *d = sv;
  }

  return compare;
}
```

Comment: If `dv == sv`, you can not only rule out finding the first difference, but also avoid the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your memory blocks are always equal, `memcmp` never reads the entire region to the end: once it finds the first discrepancy, it quits. The only time when your code reads the whole block twice is when the blocks are equal, in which case you could skip the copying altogether:

```
int memcmp_and_memcpy(void * x, const void * y, size_t n) {
    int c;
    if ((c = memcmp(x, y, n)) != 0) {
        memcpy(x, y, n);
    }
    return c;
}
```

The worst case scenario for this code is when the regions always differ in the very last byte. If you have a significant portion of such cases, you could consider rewriting the two functions as one, if your profiler tells you that it is indeed a bottleneck. However, it is very hard to compete with good library implementations of `memcpy`, because it is usually optimized quite heavily.

Comment: Indeed, in >50% of my cases, the two memory blocks are equal. Of the remainder, the difference is more likely to come at the tail end of the memory blocks. I'm currently using the early skip-out as you propose but that has an unpredictable branch which is costing a few nanos. The branch doesn't seem necessary in principle.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt. There's no need to copy anything until you detect the first difference; I believe writes are more costly than reads due to the need to keep cache coherency. There's a good chance that this code is memory bandwidth limited so heroic micro optimizations won't matter. Be warned though that I did not test it.

```
int memcmp_and_memcpy(char * x, const char * y, size_t n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    int c = 0;
    while (c == 0 && n != 0)
    {
        c = *x++ - *y++;
        --n;
    }
    memcpy(--x, --y, ++n);
    return c;
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not aware of a standard function that tells you *where* the two buffers differ or this could have been even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

memcmp and memcpy are very optimized. My proposal is to copy memcmp code to your project and change returning value to position of the first character in x and y. So First you compare with your memcmp_2 function and then memcpy from this position to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you copying values which you already determined are identical?  This needlessly dirties caches.

Here is a modification of Kaz's version that avoids needless copies (and contention for exclusive ownership of cache lines):

```
int memcmpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t size)
{ 
  if (!size) return 0;

  unsigned char *d = dst;
  const unsigned char *s = src;
  int compare = 0;

  do {
    int sv = *s++;
    unsigned char& dv = *d;

    if (dv != sv) {
        if (!compare) compare = dv - sv;
        dv = sv;
    }
  } while (--size);

  return compare;
}
```